# Using notdir within substitution reference as opposed to patsubst

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my makefile, I am stripping the file paths from a list of objects, and replacing that path with a build directory.

Using patsubst, this seems to work fine, however using substitution replacements it doesnt seem to work, e.g:

```
OBJS=/path/to/obj1.o /another/path/obj2.o
BUILD_DIR=build

$(info patsubst = $(patsubst %, $(BUILD_DIR)/%, $(notdir $(OBJS)))) 
$(info substref = $( $(notdir $(OBJS)):%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%) )
```

The output of this is :

> patsubst =  build/obj1.o  build/obj2.o
>
> substref =

Is this a shortcoming of substitution references or am I doing something wrong?

Im using GNU Make 4.1, but would like my makefile to be valid with other/older versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax is not right.  A substitution reference requires a *variable name* in the first part, and make will expand that variable and the substitution will be performed on the expansion.  You are giving `$(notdir $(OBJS))` as the thing to substitute on, and that expands to a set of strings, not a variable name.

`patsubst` works fine here so why do you need to use a substitution reference?

Comment: Ah I see, so its not possible to do this with substitution reference, without using an intermediate variable? I dont have to use it, but I prefer to as its shorter and used in a rather extensive rule. The question is more out of curiosity than necessity.

Comment: I marked correct for the explanation of the syntax being wrong. Cheers.